# Argparse-AttributeError: '_StoreAction' object has no attribute 'parse_args'

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to use argparse for the first time. I tried to write a code but unfortunately, I am getting an error.

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from data_util.data_loader import Data_load


def argparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parameters')
    parser = parser.add_argument('--dataset_path', help='data_directory',metavar='Path',
                                 default='D:/content_search/data_util/data/ArticleDataset.json')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    args = argparser()
    data_frame = Data_load(args.dataset_path)
    print(data_frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
D:\Content_search\Scripts\python.exe D:/content_search/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/content_search/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/content_search/main.py", line 15, in main
    args = argparser()
  File "D:/content_search/main.py", line 10, in argparser
    args = parser.parse_args()
AttributeError: '_StoreAction' object has no attribute 'parse_args'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please help me understand where I have made a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of this `parser` reassignment? `parser = parser.add_argument(...)`  There's nothing in the documentation that suggests doing that, is there?

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question. I found this usage in the document.
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Its calling  .add_argument method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are defining parser two times in you function **arparser()**. Remove parser = parser.add_argument and use just parser.add_argument as showed bellow.

```
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from data_util.data_loader import Data_load


def argparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parameters')
    parser.add_argument('--dataset_path', help='data_directory',metavar='Path',
                                 default='D:/content_search/data_util/data/ArticleDataset.json')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args


def main():
    args = argparser()
    data_frame = Data_load(args.dataset_path)
    print(data_frame)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It was really a stupid mistake from my side.

Comment: Check this link for some interesting details about argparse: https://realpython.com/command-line-interfaces-python-argparse/